# Azure hangs executing a stored procedure that runs instantly locally

Tags: sql, azure, stored-procedures

We have a simple stored procedure that declares a couple of variables, sets the variable from some query counts, then returns the values. The stored procedure will execute locally against sql express (2017) within .5s. The local database is a full production backup that has been restored locally with the same data as production.

When we execute the stored procedure against the same database in Azure the query will time out and execute indefinitely.

I have attempted to execute each select statement (the statements below with select count(distinct.. ) and each statement will run on Azure SQL and return the counts properly in about 1s, however when I try to use a declare or if I try to execute the selects within my stored procedure as seen below, they will fail to complete. The following code will simply not complete execution on Azure

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER proc [MySchema].[UserCounts] (
     @HUserCount int out 
    ,@NUserCount int out
) as

set @HUserCount = (
    select count(distinct userTable.Id) as UserCount
    from [MySchema1].[Active] active with (nolock)
        inner join [MySchema2].[UserActive] userTable with (nolock) on active.UserId = userTable.Id
        inner join [MySchema2].[AppSession] appSession with (nolock) on appSession.UserId = userTable.Id
    where appSession.ComponentId = '1'
)

set @NUserCount = (
    select count(distinct userTable.Id) as SUserCount
    from [MySchema1].[Active] active with (nolock)
        inner join [MySchema2].[UserActive] userTable with (nolock) on active.UserId = userTable.Id
        inner join [MySchema2].[AppSession] appSession with (nolock) on appSession.UserId = userTable.Id
    where appSession.ComponentId = '2'
)
```

The code above will hang/timeout when I execute the procedure. Also, if I just pull the code out of the stored procedure it will also fail to finish/timeout. Here's similar code that will timeout.

```
declare @HUserCount int 
declare @NUserCount int

select @HUserCount = (
    select count(distinct userTable.Id) as UserCount
    from [MySchema1].[Active] active with (nolock)
        inner join [MySchema2].[UserActive] userTable with (nolock) on active.UserId = userTable.Id
        inner join [MySchema2].[AppSession] appSession with (nolock) on appSession.UserId = userTable.Id
    where appSession.ComponentId = '1'
)

select @NUserCount = (
    select count(distinct userTable.Id) as SUserCount
    from [MySchema1].[Active] active with (nolock)
        inner join [MySchema2].[UserActive] userTable with (nolock) on active.UserId = userTable.Id
        inner join [MySchema2].[AppSession] appSession with (nolock) on appSession.UserId = userTable.Id
    where appSession.ComponentId = '2'
)
```

The following code WILL execute as expected on Azure

```
select count(distinct userTable.Id) as UserCount
    from [MySchema1].[Active] active with (nolock)
        inner join [MySchema2].[UserActive] userTable with (nolock) on active.UserId = userTable.Id
        inner join [MySchema2].[AppSession] appSession with (nolock) on appSession.UserId = userTable.Id
    where appSession.ComponentId = '1'
```

As well as

```
select count(distinct userTable.Id) as SUserCount
    from [MySchema1].[Active] active with (nolock)
        inner join [MySchema2].[UserActive] userTable with (nolock) on active.UserId = userTable.Id
        inner join [MySchema2].[AppSession] appSession with (nolock) on appSession.UserId = userTable.Id
    where appSession.ComponentId = '2'
```

Am I missing something obvious? The tables do not have a lot of rows, maybe 50,000 or less which is next to nothing for SQL Server.

EDIT/UPDATE AND WORKAROUND FOR NOW

As a temporary solution I have modified the stored proc so that it does not use set statements followed by select count(distinct ...  It seems that the select count(distinct runs fine as a standalone statement but it does not run properly when it comes after a set statement that sets a variable to the result of the select count(distinct..

Here's the resulting/working code and modified procedure

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER proc [MySchema].[UserCounts] (
     @HUserCount int out 
    ,@NUserCount int out
) as

select distinct userTable.Id into #UserCount
    from [MySchema1].[Active] active with (nolock)
        inner join [MySchema2].[UserActive] userTable with (nolock) on active.UserId = userTable.Id
        inner join [MySchema2].[AppSession] appSession with (nolock) on appSession.UserId = userTable.Id
    where appSession.ComponentId = '1'
set @HUserCount = (select count(*) from #UserCount)

select distinct userTable.Id into #SUserCount
    from [MySchema1].[Active] active with (nolock)
        inner join [MySchema2].[UserActive] userTable with (nolock) on active.UserId = userTable.Id
        inner join [MySchema2].[AppSession] appSession with (nolock) on appSession.UserId = userTable.Id
    where appSession.ComponentId = '2'
set @NUserCount = (select count(*) from #SUserCount)

DROP TABLE #UserCount
DROP TABLE #SUserCount
```

Comment: I could be misinterpreting here, but your code seems to be _altering_ the procedure, not _executing_ it...

Comment: @rickvdbosch, sorry I just posted the proc code not the code I use to execute it. It doesn't matter if the code is inside a proc or written as SQL in a query then executed, it has the same behavior (when using declares or sets).

Comment: search "parameter sniffing" , it may be an issue here.

Comment: @granadaCoder: I looked up parameter sniffing but I don't think that's why it's happening as it also happens outside of stored procs. I created a few extra sniffing protection variables and I seem to get the same result.

Comment: Since you mentioned that running the ad-hoc statements all work nice, have our tried running the procedure with the RECOMPILE option? Also, are you sure that database compatibility is the same? And what about data distribution statistics? If you check them out, they are the same on-prem and on azure?

Comment: @mauridb - I did try the RECOMPILE option, same result. The compatibility levels are the same.

Comment: I would take a look at the statistics then. Did you also checked if the estimated execution plan is the same?